# I have 1000 BUSD and some BNB stuck in an ERC-20 contract

Tags: erc-20

I know its probably not possible, but I figured I'll ask here, since I cant figure it out myself. Would anyone by any chance, know if its possible to retrieve the funds that are stuck?

Link to contract and code:

https://bscscan.com/address/0xed31f9ec173f1a8d2bba4d629414c044262f6404#code

All help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

To withdraw the tokens the contract has to use `IERC20.transfer()` or `IERC20.approve()` & `IERC20.transerFrom()`.

Unfortunately there's no such type of interaction in the contract.

To withdraw the BNB coins the contract has to use some of the function that allow transfers in solidity: `new Contract`, `selfdestruct`, `transfer`, `send`, etc. or their equivalents in assembly. Unfortunately the contract doesn't have any of those operations.